# Restful web service in .net from scratch

Tags: .net, web-services, rest

Can any one post the details to develop restful web service in .net from scratch for crud operations... or where can i find solution... thank you

I found few readings for this...
[Step by Step tutorial of REST Enabled Service in WCF](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1373-step-by-step-tutorial-rest-enabled-service.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post provides links to Piers Lawson's excellent articles on restful web service using MVC:
http://www.bloggersworld.com/index.php/restful-web-service-using-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

### I find below links, hope it will helps you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_RESTFul_CRUD_Service.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1644550.aspx/1

### For, getting basic idea of restful web service in asp.net

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.asp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)
[What is the best way to consume REST web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329256/rest-web-services-and-net)